# Can I specify a local file location in the Uri parameter for XmlSchemaSet.Add() method?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, schema

`XmlSchemaSet.Add()` method takes a `Uri`  and target namespace, but when I try to pass in a local file location it produces an error.

```
_schemaUri = @"L:\schemaDoc.xsd";
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(_schemaUri, _targetNamespace);
```

ERROR:

```
NotSupportedException was caught

The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You have confused the parameters of the **Add** method. The first parameter is the target namespace, with the second being the URI. So your code should look like this:

```
_schemaUri = @"L:\schemaDoc.xsd";
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(_targetNamespace, _schemaUri);
```

Refer to the documentation for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hh8b082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN documentation, you have the schemaUri and targetNamespace parameters in the reverse order.

From MSDN:
`XmlSchemaSet.Add Method (String, String)`
Adds the XML Schema definition language (XSD) schema at the URL specified to the XmlSchemaSet.

```
Namespace:  System.Xml.Schema
Assembly:  System.Xml (in System.Xml.dll)

public XmlSchema Add(
    string targetNamespace,
    string schemaUri
)
```

Parameters

```
targetNamespace
Type: System.String
The schema targetNamespace property, or null to use the targetNamespace specified in the schema.

schemaUri
Type: System.String
The URL that specifies the schema to load.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hh8b082(v=vs.110).aspx